Selecting specific numbers that alter in length from a String in Visual Basic
I know that I can store the first two characters from Sequence variable below:
Dim Sequence As String = "73X4"

In another variable in this case called num1, like this:
num1 = Left(Sequence, 2)

But say the sequence changed to a number with 1 digit, this would no longer work. Is there a way to assign the first number to a variable even if it is 1 - 3 digits long?
The letter will only every be one character, but the character will change between A - Z, so I can't just split on X.
num2 could be 1-3 digits long
        Dim Sequence = 73X4

        Dim num1 = 73
        Dim letter As String = "X"
        Dim num2 = 4


        num1 = Left(Sequence, 2)



Sounds like you either want to use "Split" (splitting on X) or IndexOf followed by Substring (or Left, I guess).

The first thing what you shoud do is: set Option Strict On. You are currently treating strings as integers, a great source of errors and confusion.

I would suggest looking at regular expressions

Thank you @JonSkeet I have updated the question, as the character changes for different variables.

So it is a case of "split on the first non-digit"? It would really help if you'd give multiple concrete examples instead of pseudo-code that wouldn't compile.

Using Regular Expressions
Dim sequence As String = "73X4"
Dim match As Match = Regex.Match(sequence, "^[0-9]+")

Dim num1 As Int32 = 0
If match.Success Then
    num1 = Int32.Parse(match.Value)
End If

To extract the 2nd number:
Dim sequence As String = "73X4"
Dim matches As MatchCollection = Regex.Matches(sequence, "[0-9]+")

Dim num1 As Int32 = 0
Dim num2 As Int32 = 0
If matches.Count > 0 Then
    num1 = Int32.Parse(matches(0).Value)
End If
If matches.Count > 1 Then
    num2 = Int32.Parse(matches(1).Value)
End If


Thanks @Magnus I'm getting an error on the second line of your code. Type 'Match' is not defined and. And  'Regex' is not declared. It maybe inaccessible due to its protection level. Any help would be appreciated.

Add Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

Thanks @Magnus that works perfectly, would it be possible to tell me how to extract the second number from sequence and store in num2 please?

Amazing, thanks for the quick and clear response, it's helped me out a lot. I've set the question as answered now. Cheers

If possible would you be able to include how to store the X in a variable, this letter can change but will only ever be 1 character?

@LloydThomas next time include all your requirements in the original question.

You could use LINQ's TakeWhile with Char.IsDigit:
Dim intStart As String = String.Concat(sequence.TakeWhile(AddressOf Char.IsDigit))
Dim num1 As Int32 = If(intStart.Any(), Int32.Parse(intStart), Int32.MinValue)

By the way: you should set Option Strict On. You are currently treating strings as integers, a great source of errors and confusion. That would not compile normally, which is good.

Thanks @Tim I have set Option Strict On now, but receive the following error on the second line of code you've provided: 'System.FormatException: 'Input string was not in a correct format.' - Any help would be appreciated.

@LloydThomas: Have you used exactly the code i've provided? intStart can either be an empty string or a string with digits only. This always can be parsed to Int32, so your exception should never happen. In case it's an empty string the intStart.Any() returns false and Int32.MinValue is assigned to num1(so you should check for that afterwards as an invalid number). Which your sample text "73X4" num1 becomes 73 with my code.

@LloydThomas Are you using some Arabic numerals in your string?

No I'm not using Arabic numerals.

Everyone clear that Arabic numerals are 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, right?

Using this method, Integer.TryParse conveniently checks for successful parsing: Dim n As Integer
If Not Integer.TryParse(New String(s.TakeWhile(AddressOf Char.IsDigit).ToArray()), n) Then n = Integer.MinValue, this way the string result of the LINQ is only used once, so there would be no need to assign it to a variable.
